# how to decode sound from mp3 to pcm by mpg123 library

Tags: android, eclipse, audiotrack

```html
int minSize =AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize( 45100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT );        
   track = new AudioTrack( AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,45100 , 
     AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 
     minSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);  
   track.setStereoVolume(1f,1f);
   while(true)
   {
    Log.e(""," sizewe are using for track buffer is "+minSize);
    int i = 0;                                                          //  Read the file into the "music" array
    music=new short[4188];

    while (dis.available() > 0)
    {
     music[i] =  dis.readShort();
     i++;
     if(i==4188)
      break;
    }
    Log.e("","music lengh= "+music.length+"  and dis.available="+dis.available());
    track.play();    
    track.write(music,0, music.length);
    track.flush();
    track.stop();
   }
```

could some one tell me how to decode sound when we playing a large mp3 file in audiotrack using bytebuffer ,i want to decode it in real time when playing the song .. here i am getting song from .aiff file which is a pcm format 
first: i want to play a mp3 file by audiotrack class
second: .wav is also a pcm file but it is not playing.

```
thanks in advance
```

Comment: _".wav is also a pcm file but it is not playing."_ A WAV file contains headers in addition to the PCM data. You haven't shown how you parse the file or explained exactly what _"it is not playing"_ means, so it's impossible to say what the problem might be.

Comment: i mean when i am playing .wav format i am not getting any sound.and please tell me how to decode file by mpg123 library